# How to Kafka Connect Elasticsearch with SSL?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Hi after looking at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html#security, I am not sure which config I need to Kafka Connect to an Elasticsearch endpoint at https.

I am able to Kafka Connect to a different non-https Elasticsearch, and on a regular client, I can connect to https by turning off SSL verification.

This example from a different service provider https://help.aiven.io/en/articles/2349675-aiven-kafka-elasticsearch-sink-connector makes it seem like `connection.url`, `connection.username`, and `connection.password` is enough for https, but I am getting the error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't start ElasticsearchSinkTask due to connection error:
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:132)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:122)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:115)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:57)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:206)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:130)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 40 more
```

Running Confluent 5.2.2 locally, Elasticsearch 6.8.3.

Config:

```
{
  "name": "sink-elasticsearch-mytable-ssl",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

    "connection.url": "https://xxx.databases.appdomain.cloud:30810",
    "connection.username": "ibm_cloud_xxx",
    "connection.password": "xxx",

    "type.name": "type.name=kafka-connect",
    "topics": "postgresql-mytable",
    "key.ignore": true
  }
}
```

I am using a managed Elasticsearch service, so all I have been given is the username/password and TLS cert, so I don't see keystore/truststore stuff. What is the rest of what I need to Kafka Connect Elasticsearch with SSL?

Comment: What version of Kafka Connect are you using? which version of the Elasticsearch sink connector? Can you edit your question to include the connector JSON config too please.

Comment: Running Confluent 5.2.2 locally and whatever is bundled with that. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Elastic Cloud you just pass the username and password:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "connection.url": "https://myclusterid.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243",
  "connection.username": "elastic",
  "connection.password": "covfefe",
  […]
```

Comment: I tested this out and it seems like it's a versioning issue. I tried out Elastic Cloud on 6.8.3 and got the same failure. Then I upgraded it to 7.4.0 and it successfully connected.