# How to connect Elasticsearch deployed by Elastic Operator correctly in a Kafka connector?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have some CDC data in Kafka. Now I am trying to sink from Kafka to Elasticsearch. Here is what I have done so far:

### Step 1 - Deploy Elasticsearch in Kubernetes (succeed)

I deployed Elasticsearch in Kubernetes by following this tutorial using Elastic Operator:

1. Deploy ECK in your Kubernetes cluster: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html
2. Deploy an Elasticsearch cluster: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: hm-elasticsearch
  namespace: elastic
spec:
  version: 7.14.0
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

Based on the tutorial, I can succeed calling by providing username `elastic` and password `passw0rd` in the header by

```
curl -u "elastic:passw0rd" -k "https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200"
```

which returns

```
{
    "name": "hm-elasticsearch-es-default-0",
    "cluster_name": "hm-elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid": "TWgIk0YGR_GVr7IJZcW62g",
    "version": {
        "number": "7.14.0",
        "build_flavor": "default",
        "build_type": "docker",
        "build_hash": "dd5a0a2acaa2045ff9624f3729fc8a6f40835aa1",
        "build_date": "2021-07-29T20:49:32.864135063Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "8.9.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

### Step 2 - Add ElasticsearchSinkConnector (failed to connect Elasticsearch)

Now I am trying to adding ElasticsearchSinkConnector, however, I am having issue to set it up.

I saw [How to Kafka Connect Elasticsearch with SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381240/how-to-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-with-ssl). Elastic Cloud just needs just to pass the username and password. So I thought it would be similar to mine.

Also, based on [this ElasticsearchSinkConnector config](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/unwrap-smt/es-sink.json), I wrote my config, and then try to verify by

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://hm-connect-cluster-connect-api.kafka:8083/connector-plugins/io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector/config/validate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "opa_db_server.public.roles",
    "connection.url": "https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200",
    "connection.username": "elastic",
    "connection.password": "passw0rd",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "role_id",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete"
}'
```

It returns the error

```
{
    "name": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "error_count": 3,
    "groups": [
        "Common",
        "Transforms",
        "Predicates",
        "Error Handling",
        "Transforms: unwrap",
        "Transforms: key",
        "Connector",
        "Data Conversion",
        "Proxy",
        "Security",
        "Kerberos",
        "Data Stream"
    ],
    "configs": [
        // ...
        {
            "definition": {
                "name": "connection.url",
                "type": "LIST",
                "required": true,
                "default_value": null,
                "importance": "HIGH",
                "documentation": "The comma-separated list of one or more Elasticsearch URLs, such as ``http://eshost1:9200,http://eshost2:9200`` or ``https://eshost3:9200``. HTTPS is used for all connections if any of the URLs starts with ``https:``. A URL without a protocol is treated as ``http``.",
                "group": "Connector",
                "width": "LONG",
                "display_name": "Connection URLs",
                "dependents": [],
                "order": 1
            },
            "value": {
                "name": "connection.url",
                "value": "https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200",
                "recommended_values": [],
                "errors": [
                    "Could not connect to Elasticsearch. Error message: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
                ],
                "visible": true
            }
        },
        {
            "definition": {
                "name": "connection.username",
                "type": "STRING",
                "required": false,
                "default_value": null,
                "importance": "MEDIUM",
                "documentation": "The username used to authenticate with Elasticsearch. The default is the null, and authentication will only be performed if  both the username and password are non-null.",
                "group": "Connector",
                "width": "SHORT",
                "display_name": "Connection Username",
                "dependents": [],
                "order": 2
            },
            "value": {
                "name": "connection.username",
                "value": "elastic",
                "recommended_values": [],
                "errors": [
                    "Could not authenticate the user. Check the 'connection.username' and 'connection.password'. Error message: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
                ],
                "visible": true
            }
        },
        {
            "definition": {
                "name": "connection.password",
                "type": "PASSWORD",
                "required": false,
                "default_value": null,
                "importance": "MEDIUM",
                "documentation": "The password used to authenticate with Elasticsearch. The default is the null, and authentication will only be performed if  both the username and password are non-null.",
                "group": "Connector",
                "width": "SHORT",
                "display_name": "Connection Password",
                "dependents": [],
                "order": 3
            },
            "value": {
                "name": "connection.password",
                "value": "[hidden]",
                "recommended_values": [],
                "errors": [
                    "Could not authenticate the user. Check the 'connection.username' and 'connection.password'. Error message: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
                ],
                "visible": true
            }
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

The full verification response with all fields can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Hongbo-Miao/34e51bfe91dfd169259ab81ba3fd942a) which has all info for the config field can be used.

## UPDATE 1 (12/8/2021):

I found [this document](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/security.html#step-4-configure-the-connector) which has more config regarding SSL

```
"elastic.security.protocol": "SSL"
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "/path/to/keystore.jks"
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "xxx"
"elastic.https.ssl.key.password": "xxx"
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type": "JKS"
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "/path/to/truststore.jks"
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "xxx"
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type": "JKS"
"elastic.https.ssl.protocol": "TLS"
```

In my case, I only need provider username and password to succeed. But in above config, there is no place to provide username. So I am not sure how to really write it correctly.

## UPDATE 2 (12/9/2021):

I have these pods running

```
> kubectl get pods --namespace=elastic
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hm-kibana-kb-77d4d9b456-m6th9        1/1     Running   0          6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-default-0        1/1     Running   0          35h
```

and these secrets

```
kubectl get secrets --namespace=elastic
NAME                                             TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
hm-kibana-kibana-user                            Opaque                                1      6d3h
elastic-hm-kibana-kibana-user                    Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-kibana-kb-http-ca-internal                    Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-http-ca-internal             Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-http-certs-internal          Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public            Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-kibana-kb-es-ca                               Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-kibana-kb-http-certs-internal                 Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-kibana-kb-http-certs-public                   Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-transport-ca-internal        Opaque                                2      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-transport-certs-public       Opaque                                1      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-remote-ca                    Opaque                                1      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-elastic-user                 Opaque                                1      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-internal-users               Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-xpack-file-realm             Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-default-es-config            Opaque                                1      6d3h
hm-elasticsearch-es-default-es-transport-certs   Opaque                                3      6d3h
hm-kibana-kb-config                              Opaque                                2      6d3h
```

I am able to save `ca.crt`, `tls.crt`, `tls.key` locally by

```
kubectl get secret hm-elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public \
  --namespace=elastic \
  --output=go-template='{{index .data "ca.crt" | base64decode }}' \
  > ca.crt

kubectl get secret hm-elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public \
  --namespace=elastic \
  --output=go-template='{{index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}' \
  > tls.crt

kubectl get secret hm-elasticsearch-es-http-certs-internal \
  --namespace=elastic \
  --output=go-template='{{index .data "tls.key" | base64decode }}' \
  > tls.key
```

Before I have to use `-k` flag to disable the certificate verification to let the `curl` succeed. Now in Kubernetes, I can succeed without the flag:

```
curl --request GET \
     --url https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200 \
     --cacert ca.crt \
     --key tls.key \
     --cert tls.crt \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -u "elastic:passw0rd"
```

Also, I succeed generating `keystore.jks` by

```
openssl pkcs12 -export \
  -in tls.crt \
  -inkey tls.key \
  -CAfile ca.crt \
  -caname root \
  -out keystore.p12 \
  -password pass:SFLzyT8DPkGGjDtn \
  -name hm-elasticsearch-keystore

keytool -importkeystore \
  -srckeystore keystore.p12 \
  -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
  -srcstorepass SFLzyT8DPkGGjDtn \
  -deststorepass MPx57vkACsRWKVap \
  -destkeypass MPx57vkACsRWKVap \
  -destkeystore keystore.jks \
  -alias hm-elasticsearch-keystore
```

I am still not sure how **truststore** in UPDATE 1 is. But now I can fill this part regarding **keystore**:

```
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "/path/to/keystore.jks"
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "MPx57vkACsRWKVap"
"elastic.https.ssl.key.password": "MPx57vkACsRWKVap"
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type": "JKS"
```

However, my `keystore.jks` is currently on my laptop locally. My Elasticsearch and ElasticsearchSinkConnector is running in the Kubernetes.

Where does this `"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "/path/to/keystore.jks"` refer to?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-tls-certificates.html#k8s-setting-up-your-own-certificate

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer I have checked the link. It is for providing own certificate. However, even I have my own `ca.crt`, `tls.crt`, `tls.key`, I am still not sure how to fill those fields in the config..

Comment: 1) You need to convert these files to JKS files 2) Otherwise, outside of Connect, does ES-API work with just username and password? e.g. using `curl -u`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 1) I will try to find a good tutorial how to convert. 2) Yes, it works well with just username and password like `curl -u "elastic:passw0rd" -k " https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200"` in my question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I assume the curl call is from the connect container? The only other idea I can think of is that since Connect uses a JVM-based HTTP client, then those certs are probably needed for it, so you'd add all those SSL properties and the HTTPS user+pass

Comment: @OneCricketeer oh that cURL will succeed in terminal or Postman. In Postman, it only succeed when I disable SSL certificate verification. I think your suggestion for JKS is right direction for me. I will try and report back if I succeed, thanks!

Comment: @HongboMiao how did you deploy kafka-connect? I guess what you can do is mount a volume that can be shared in kakfa. so that you can place your jks in there and will be accessible to kafka pods.

Comment: Thanks @YassineAbdul-Rahman I made it! Posted in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add more background. The way I deployed Kafka is using [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/):

```
kubectl create namespace kafka
kubectl apply --filename="https://strimzi.io/install/latest?namespace=kafka" --namespace=kafka
kubectl apply --filename=https://strimzi.io/examples/latest/kafka/kafka-persistent-single.yaml --namespace=kafka
```

Following the UPDATE 2 in the question, once got **keystore.jks**, I created the secret by

```
kubectl create secret generic hm-elasticsearch-keystore \
  --from-file=keystore.jks \
  --namespace=kafka
```

I have files

**kafkaconnect.yaml**

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: hm-connect-cluster
  namespace: kafka
  annotations:
    # use-connector-resources configures this KafkaConnect
    # to use KafkaConnector resources to avoid
    # needing to call the Connect REST API directly
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  image: hongbomiao/hm-connect-debezium:latest
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapServers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9093
  tls:
    trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert
        certificate: ca.crt
  config:
    config.storage.replication.factor: 1
    offset.storage.replication.factor: 1
    status.storage.replication.factor: 1
    config.providers: file
    config.providers.file.class: org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
  externalConfiguration:
    volumes:
      - name: hm-elasticsearch-keystore-volume
        secret:
          secretName: hm-elasticsearch-keystore
```

**elasticsearch-sink-kafkaconnector.yaml**

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-sink-connector
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: hm-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  # https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/configuration_options.html
  config:
    connector.class: "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector"
    tasks.max: "1"
    topics: "opa_db_server.public.roles"
    connection.url: "https://hm-elasticsearch-es-http.elastic:9200"
    connection.username: "elastic"
    connection.password: "passw0rd"
    transforms: "unwrap,key"
    transforms.unwrap.type: "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
    transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: "false"
    transforms.key.type: "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key"
    transforms.key.field: "role_id"
    key.ignore: "false"
    behavior.on.null.values: "delete"
    elastic.security.protocol: "SSL"
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/hm-elasticsearch-volume/keystore.jks"
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password: "MPx57vkACsRWKVap"
    elastic.https.ssl.key.password: "MPx57vkACsRWKVap"
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type: "JKS"
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/hm-elasticsearch-keystore-volume/keystore.jks"
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password: "MPx57vkACsRWKVap"
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type: "JKS"
    elastic.https.ssl.protocol: "TLS1.3"
```

Note keystore and truststore share the same one.

Then just need run

```
kubectl apply --filename=kafkaconnect.yaml
kubectl apply --filename=elasticsearch-sink-kafkaconnector.yaml
```

Now it works!

Comment: so I am stuck with this... I have followed your guide very closely. I am even using image ```image: hongbomiao/hm-kafka-connect:latest``` 



The Error I get is 

```2022-12-09 17:01:02,917 ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors/elasticsearch-sink-connector/config (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper) [qtp1793469566-21]
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLS1.3 SSLContext not available```

Answer (score 0):

After some research found a good way to solve this problem.

1. Install cert-manager (https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/)
2. Generate self-signed issuer & certificate via cert-manager (with additional keystores.jks option):

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: es-ca-issuer
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: es-jks-cert
spec:
  secretName: es-jks-secret
  dnsNames:
    - <your es internal endpoint service name>
  issuerRef:
    name: es-ca-issuer
  keystores:
    jks:
      create: true
      passwordSecretRef:
        key: password
        name: jks-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jks-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: ZXhhbXBsZQ==
```

3. Configure your Elasticsearch cluster to use your self-signed certificate:

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: es
spec:
  version: 8.9.1
  http:
    tls:
      certificate:
        secretName: es-jks-secret
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

4. Prepare your Kafka Connect manifest to import secret which contains jks key:

```yaml
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: connect-elastic
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: <kafka cluster name>
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapServers: <kafka-cluster-bootstrap-service>:9093
  tls:
    trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: <kafka-clutser-cert-secret>
        certificate: ca.crt
  config:
    config.providers: secrets
    config.providers.secrets.class: io.strimzi.kafka.KubernetesSecretConfigProvider
    group.id: elastic-connect
    config.storage.topic: elastic-connect-configs
    offset.storage.topic: elastic-connect-offsets
    status.storage.topic: elastic-connect-status
    config.storage.replication.factor: -1
    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
  build:
    output:
      type: docker
      image: <docker registry>
      pushSecret: <docker regcred secret name>
    plugins:
      - name: kafka-connect-elasticsearch
        artifacts:
          - type: maven
            group: io.confluent
            artifact: kafka-connect-elasticsearch
            version: 14.0.3
            repository: https://packages.confluent.io/maven/
  externalConfiguration:
    volumes:
      - name: es-jks-volume
        secret:
          secretName: es-jks-secret
```

5. We use `KubernetesSecretConfigProvider` to pass the secrets to final connector. We should configure `connect-elastic-connect` to access `jks-secret` and `es-es-elastic-user` via RBAC permissions:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: connector-configuration-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    resourceNames: ["es-es-elastic-user", "jks-secret"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: connector-configuration-role-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: connect-elastic-connect
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: connect-postgres-connect
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: connector-configuration-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

6. After that we are ready to deploy your Kafka Elasticseacrh connector:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: connector-elastic
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: connect-elastic
spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    connector.class: "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector"
    topics: "..."
    connection.url: https://es-es-internal-http:9200
    connection.username: elastic
    connection.password: ${secrets:default/es-es-elastic-user:elastic}
    elastic.security.protocol: "SSL"
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/es-jks-volume/keystore.jks"
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password: ${secrets:default/jks-secret:password}
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type: "JKS"
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/es-jks-volume/truststore.jks"
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password: ${secrets:default/jks-secret:password}
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type: "JKS"
```